# Will someone gain martyrdom if they died while going to or returning from the mesjid?

Tags: masjid, martyr

As-Salamu alaikum brothers and sisters, if someone dies while going or returning to the mesjid, will they be considered a shaheed?

Jazakum Allah khayran and Baraka Allahu feekum.